# Client to specific client communication through a server

Tags: java, sockets

I have successfully implemented a server -client application where i have maintained a list of clients connected to the server in an array.What i do not understand is how will the client tell the server about the client the message is sent for .Like if server A has 3 clients connected lets say a,b and c.Now if a wants to send a message to c how will it tell the server about it?
i want the client to send a request to server asking to connect to client c ,the server asks client c for permission and if c accepts a and c can send messages back and forth until one of them disconnects

Comment: "a" sends message to server A, message contains who should recieve that message and what is the content of that message. Server A then sends message to client c with its content.

Comment: i want the client to send a request to server asking to connect to client c ,the server asks client c for permission and if c accepts a and c can send messages back and forth until one of them disconnects .

Comment: And what is your problem? If you want to connect "a" and "c" directly, it is not possible, every message has to be send through the server.

Comment: i want to implement a chat application where a server has different connected clients and any client can connect to any other client through the server and communicate through the server and can quit the  connection whenever desired.

Comment: no no ,messages are to be sent through the server but that message has to be for some client rather than being sent to every client in the list maintained

Comment: Well, then clients only sends messages to the server and server has to manage everyting (remember who is connected to who etc.)

Comment: so how will the client request the server to connect it to client c?

Comment: i know the server will do every thing but the client will have to ask the server to conenct it to client c ,how will the client do that>

Comment: If you "successfully implemented a server -client application", then server can send message to any client and any client can send message to the server, right? The client sends message, for example "I want to join client with id:10", server recieves that message, parse it, and do thing you want to do.

Comment: sending messages for connection is not a good idea i guess .There should be some other way for requesting a connection rather than sending messages .right?

Comment: Everything is "sending messages", it is only up to you, what clients send and how server parse that messages. However if you want to use something more advanced, there is Java RMI, which works as easy as you directly call methods from client to server or vice versa. That libraries are sending messages "inside", so you dont see them and you dont have to manually parse them (message recieves, is parsed and aprropriated method with appropriated parameters is executed)

Comment: Here is working example, you can try it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation

Comment: thanks for the help .It was helpfull .I was trying to learn socket programming for later use in jsp learning .I have another question for you and i hope you dont mind me asking so many questions .What things do i need to learn to become a good freelancing developer for java and jsp?as well as android?

Comment: You do not need to know socket programming for jsp. To be good developer, you need practice, practice and practice :D. It does not matter what you do, if you do it. Usually creating game is fun enough and you learn a lot, especially, when your game grows "bigger" and you find problems which you didnt see in smaller projects.

Comment: And SQL, learn SQL, its almost standard these days for any programmer.

Answer (score 1):

For IM (Instant Messaging), you can look at XMPP Servers and clients, which are very popular in chat application, even gtalk works on them.

XMPP Server : jabber server.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is exchanging all the messages (in a given protocol) through a server and which intermediates everything. If you want direct communication between the clients, take a look at p2p or peer-to-peer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer).

Your question is very similar to this one: [Client-Server-Client communication using Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332799/client-server-client-communication-using-sockets?rq=1)